# system.ntfs_reparse_data: Operation not supported - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, mount, ntfs, symbolic-link, ntfs-3g

I am trying to use this guide: https://serverfault.com/questions/165389/create-ntfs-symbolic-links-from-within-linux

To try and copy reparse data from a symlink created in windows to another file (just playing around with reparse points)

using the following commands:

```
# Display the reparse data of the file source-file
getfattr -h -e hex -n system.ntfs_reparse_data test3.txt
```

However, this gives me the error:

```
system.ntfs_reparse_data: Operation not supported
```

The file i am trying this on is a windows symlink, and shows up on dir /R as a symlink:

```
02-11-2018  20:08    <SYMLINK>      test3.txt
```

ntfs-3g is installed, this is Ubuntu 18.04, installed from the windows store, on win 10.

The issue seems to be with mounting, according to ubuntu, the disk is mounted with drvfs under /mnt/c, so if that is the problem and someone can tell me how to mount it as ntfs, that wouild be great!

Any ideas?